# Defining generic function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, checkbox, syntax

I have a simple function that shows a div when the user clicks on a given checkbox. I'd like to have the same behaviour on another checkbox, so that's why I'd like to generalize it as a function passing the element to be shown.

But I'm not aware of the syntax on Jquery to do so. And it's triggering automatically when the page loads. Does anybody has an idea?

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#transcricao").change( 
    function(){ 
        if ($('.form_transcr').css('display') === 'none') {
            $('.form_transcr').fadeIn(); 
        } else {
            $('.form_transcr').fadeOut();
        }
    }
); //This is working fine!


$("#traducao").change( show_hide($('.form_trad')) ); 
//This is auto-trigerring without user action...

});
```

Here's my function:

```
function show_hide($elm){ 

//This is the "generalized" function that I'd like to use on both
//checkboxes, just passing the element.

if ($($elm).css('display') === 'none') {
        $($elm).fadeIn(); 
    } else {
        $($elm).fadeOut();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Isn't that what `fadeToggle()` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its auto-triggering without user action because you are invoking it.

Use

```
$("#traducao").change(function () {
    show_hide($('.form_trad'));
});
```

As you are passing jQuery object so use it directly

```
function show_hide($elm) {
    //This is the "generalized" function that I'd like to use on both
    //checkboxes, just passing the element.
    if ($elm.css('display') === 'none') {
        $elm.fadeIn();
    } else {
        $elm.fadeOut();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `.change()` should be a function. You're not passing a function, you're *calling* the function.

```
$("#traducao").change(function() {
    show_hide($('.form_trad'));
} );
```

BTW, your `show_hide` function seems to be equivalent to jQuery's `fadeToggle` method, so it can be:

```
$("#traducao").change(function() {
    $(".form_trad").fadeToggle();
});
```